# How can I make a top 10 videos on iMovie? Like does it have a feature on the Storyboards where I can do this?

Tags: video-editor, video-recording, video-capture, imovie, iphone

If it matters I'm trying to do this on iOS would I need resources from other apps to make the video

Comment: Do you want to edit and combine various videos into one video? Your question is not very clear. Are you looking for resources to do this with apps on an Apple device?

Comment: Maybe watch tutorials on YouTube about iMovie. If those don't help and you have a specific question you can ask it here. But, in my opinion your current question is way too broad to answer here.